# Windows Phone 8.1 IE11 parsing issue with nested list and contenteditable div

Tags: html, internet-explorer, windows-phone-8

May be someone has already faced with such strange issue. I would appreciate if you could give me any usefull advices.

> SPOILER: working html fiddle is located the end of question.

**TASK:**

I'm developing just another WYSIWYG editor based on `<div contenteditable>`. One of main feature for user will be working with nested lists.

**PREPARE**

I'm in editor, working with list which was received from server and put to `<div>` in innerHTML:

*HTML:*

```
<div contenteditable="true">
    <ul>
        <li>
            One
            <ul>
                <li>
                    Two
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

*Browser:*

> - One
>
>   - Two

In real life, innerHTML, received from server, will be inline, of course:

```
<div contenteditable="true"><ul><li>One<ul><li>Two</li></ul></li></ul></div>
```

Assuming, that I need to delete letter **e** in word **One**. I put caret after the word and press Backspace as usual.

**PROBLEM IN IE Mobile**

In Chrome, Safari, desktop IE11 everything will be OK - letter **e** will be deleted, and caret remain in the right position. But in Windows Phone IE, caret will jump to the next position in list - before word **Two**.

Sorry for huge explanation, I put this HTML on google hosting, so you can try with your own Windows Phone and try delete letter **e** with backspace:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />
    </head>
    <body>

        CORRECT backspace behaviour:
        <div contenteditable="true">
            <ul>
                <li>
                    One
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            Two
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        INCORRECT backspace behaviour:
        <div contenteditable="true">
            <ul><li>One<ul><li>Two</li></ul></li></ul>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

http://www.googledrive.com/host/0Bw1Lu-P82yZ_TzNFa1VVTVpjbms

P.S.: yes, i noticed that despite the "equality" of these two div's, IE is adding one space after each word in the first variant. May be it can be a workaround if server will add `&nbsp` in each line.

> UPDATE: this question is related to Windows Phone IE only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as quick workaround - to add `<br>` in the end of each `text` element that belongs to `<li>` containing nested `<ul>`.

```
<ul><li>One<br><ul><li>Two<br></li></ul></li></ul>
```